# Не могу понять ошибку в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, bs4

Есть xml(упрощенный):

```
<items>
    <item>
        <issn>123123</issn>
    </item>
    <item>
        <eissn>56789</eissn>
    </item>
</items>
```

И функция:

```
def get_issn_eissn(item) -> str:
        publ_issn = item.find("issn")
        if publ_issn in item:
            return publ_issn
        else:
            publ_eissn = item.find("eissn")
            return publ_eissn

def get_write():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

    for item in root.select('item'):
        a = get_issn_eissn(item)
        print(a)
```

Эта функция призвана передать из xml либо `issn`, либо `eissn`. В зависимости от того, что попадется в теге `item`. Но она выводит только `None`. Подскажите, где ошибка?

Желаемый результат:
123123,
56789

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: А если добавить в функцию print на каждую строку и посмотреть какой print был последний, то какой return был?

Comment: gil9red, заменила return на print, в том и другом случае - печатает None

Comment: Я не говорил заменять return на print, а добавить принты по всюду, чтобы вы сами определили место где функция завершилась и каким путем она до этого дошла. А так, у вас код напрашивается на один return: `return item.find("issn") or item.find("eissn")`

Comment: Кст, добавляйте @ перед ником (например, @gil9red), иначе может не прийти уведомление об комментарии адресату

Comment: @gil9red, на счет @ усвоила. Действительно, убрала все лишнее, оставила один return и все сработало. Спасибо Вам!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в одну строку:

```py
def get_issn_eissn(item):
    return item.find("issn") or item.find("eissn")
```

Если непонятно решение с `or`, то оно может быть представлено через `if` как:

```py
def get_issn_eissn(item):
    item = item.find("issn")
    if item:
        return item
    
    return item.find("eissn")
```